# Error in ggplot2: Use show_guide = TRUE or show_guide = FALSE to display or suppress the guide display. (Defunct; last used in version 0.8.9)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm getting the following error while using `ggplot2`:

```
df=iris
m=as.matrix(cbind(df$Petal.Length, df$Petal.Width),ncol=2)
cl=(kmeans(m,3))
df$cluster=factor(cl$cluster)
centers=as.data.frame(cl$centers)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, color=cluster )) + 
     geom_point() + 
     geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color='Center')) +
     geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color='Center'), size=52, alpha=.3, legend=FALSE)

Error: Use show_guide = TRUE or show_guide = FALSE to display or suppress the guide display. (Defunct; last used in version 0.8.9)
```

My version.string is `version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)`

Comment: I'm following this post http://www.r-bloggers.com/bot-botany-k-means-and-ggplot2/

Comment: ah, I see. I didn't post two extra lines before importing ggplot2. Anwyas, my error still remains. Are you not getting the same error? Is your version of R different?

Comment: Yes. Just follow the recommendation: use `show_guide` instead of `legend`.

Comment: Thanks. Would be more helpful if that recommendation suggested what you suggested. It has no mention of "legend"

Comment: With `ggplot2_1.0.1`, I get  `Error: "legend" argument in geom_XXX and stat_XXX is deprecated. Use show_guide = TRUE or show_guide = FALSE for display or suppress the guide display. (Defunct; last used in version 0.8.9)`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of metioning legend false in `geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color='Center'), size=52, alpha=.3, legend=FALSE)`. Do it using `guides()` function

Try following

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, color=cluster )) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color='Center')) +
  geom_point(data=centers, aes(x=V1,y=V2, color='Center'), size=52, alpha=.3) +
  guides(color = FALSE)
```